# Datatable not updating using SelectInput in Shiny Presentation

Tags: shiny, dt

I hope someone can help me out on this seemingly simple issue. I am trying to make a shiny presentation that demonstrates how a shiny app works without needing to open it up in a browser. My problem is simply that I cannot get the output data table to update when I change the `selectInput()` dropdown.

Step 1 is to generate a list of data frames, step 2 is to summarise the data (mean, sd, etc...), and step 3 is to get the data to display in a `datatable`. The code below only shows the output for one of these 'drugs'.

I feel like I'm missing something simple... help is greatly appreciated!

Reproducible example is here:

```
# YAML
---
title: "Mytitle"
author: "Me"
date: "05/10/2023"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation: 
  smaller: false
  
runtime: shiny
---
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

#Make some fake data
eg.drugs <- list(Bunnies = data.frame(SampleID = LETTERS[1:20],
                                      SampleType = c(rep("QC1", 5), rep("QC2", 5), rep("Patient", 10)),
                                      Cal1 = c(round(rnorm(5, 35, 5),2), round(rnorm(5, 75, 10),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by=10))),
                                      Cal2 = c(round(rnorm(5, 32, 4.5),2), round(rnorm(5, 80, 11)), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by=10)))),
                 Kittens = data.frame(SampleID = LETTERS[1:20],
                                      SampleType = c(rep("QC1", 5), rep("QC2", 5), rep("Patient", 10)),
                                      Cal1 = c(round(rnorm(5, 34, 5),2), round(rnorm(5, 70, 10),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by = 10))),
                                      Cal2 = c(round(rnorm(5, 38, 4.5),2), round(rnorm(5, 80, 11),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by = 10)))),
                 Unicorns = data.frame(SampleID = LETTERS[1:20],
                                      SampleType = c(rep("QC1", 5), rep("QC2", 5), rep("Patient", 10)),
                                      Cal1 = c(round(rnorm(5, 7.5, 1),2), round(rnorm(5, 55, 3),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by = 10))),
                                      Cal2 = c(round(rnorm(5, 9, 2),2), round(rnorm(5, 51, 4.5),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by = 10)))))
```

```
fluidPage(
          fluidRow(sidebarPanel(
            selectInput('drug', "Choose Drug:", choices = names(eg.drugs)), width = 12), 
            width = 6),
          fluidRow(mainPanel({
            DTOutput('table')
          }, width = 12), width = 6)
)
      output.dat <- reactive({
             sum.dat <- lapply(eg.drugs, function(x){
                                  x %>%
                                  gather(SpecID, Value, 3:4) %>%
                                  filter(SampleType != "Patient") %>%
                                  group_by(SampleType, SpecID) %>%
                                  summarise(Mean = round(mean(Value),2),
                                            SD = round(sd(Value),3)) %>%
                                  pivot_wider(id_cols = SampleType, names_from = SpecID, values_from = c("Mean", "SD"))
             
              })
             return(sum.dat)
      })

     renderDT({
        datatable(output.dat()[[input$drug]])
      }
     )
```

I've used R and Shiny for a while, but this is my first try at a Shiny presentation. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the output `renderDT` to an output "component" in your ui. Within your `mainPanel` is the component `DTOutput('table')`.

To get your output displayed there you have to assign it to this component by:

```
   output$table <-  renderDT({
            datatable(output.dat()[[input$drug]])
    }
```

##### EDIT: Whole App

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

#Make some fake data
eg.drugs <- list(Bunnies = data.frame(SampleID = LETTERS[1:20],
                                      SampleType = c(rep("QC1", 5), rep("QC2", 5), rep("Patient", 10)),
                                      Cal1 = c(round(rnorm(5, 35, 5),2), round(rnorm(5, 75, 10),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by=10))),
                                      Cal2 = c(round(rnorm(5, 32, 4.5),2), round(rnorm(5, 80, 11)), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by=10)))),
                 Kittens = data.frame(SampleID = LETTERS[1:20],
                                      SampleType = c(rep("QC1", 5), rep("QC2", 5), rep("Patient", 10)),
                                      Cal1 = c(round(rnorm(5, 34, 5),2), round(rnorm(5, 70, 10),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by = 10))),
                                      Cal2 = c(round(rnorm(5, 38, 4.5),2), round(rnorm(5, 80, 11),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by = 10)))),
                 Unicorns = data.frame(SampleID = LETTERS[1:20],
                                       SampleType = c(rep("QC1", 5), rep("QC2", 5), rep("Patient", 10)),
                                       Cal1 = c(round(rnorm(5, 7.5, 1),2), round(rnorm(5, 55, 3),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by = 10))),
                                       Cal2 = c(round(rnorm(5, 9, 2),2), round(rnorm(5, 51, 4.5),2), jitter(seq(from=1, to=100, by = 10)))))


# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
        fluidRow(sidebarPanel(
                selectInput('drug', "Choose Drug:", choices = names(eg.drugs)), width = 12), 
                width = 6),
        fluidRow(mainPanel({
                DTOutput('table')
        }, width = 12), width = 6)
)

# Define server logic required 
server <- function(input, output) {

        output.dat <- reactive({
                sum.dat <- lapply(eg.drugs, function(x){
                        x %>%
                                gather(SpecID, Value, 3:4) %>%
                                filter(SampleType != "Patient") %>%
                                group_by(SampleType, SpecID) %>%
                                summarise(Mean = round(mean(Value),2),
                                          SD = round(sd(Value),3)) %>%
                                pivot_wider(id_cols = SampleType, names_from = SpecID, values_from = c("Mean", "SD"))
                        
                })
                return(sum.dat)
        })
        
        output$table <- renderDT({
                datatable(output.dat()[[input$drug]])
        }
        )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It actually doesn't seem to matter if I have the `output$table` or not.  The table is still not updating!

Comment: You have to assign it in the `server <- function(input, output) {}` section. I updated my answer to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, needing to use the 'normal' `ui` and `server` setup is what I was missing. Not too many examples out there for Presentations - thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh wow, I was thinking about a normal shiny app, sorry! But I'm glad it still helped.. kind of.. :) 
A shiny presentation within a R Markdown file worked fine with your code..